# Database hangs if not used

Tags: postgresql, go, postgresql-9.4

I have a web application I am starting. Works fine upon startup but if I leave it (for say, an hour) and hit it with another request the query hangs. I thought about closing it after each query then opening up a new connection but the docs explicitly say "It is rare to Close a DB, as the DB handle is meant to be long-lived and shared between many goroutines.". What am I doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
  "database/sql"
  "log"
  "net/http"
  _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var Db *sql.DB

func main() {
  var err error
  Db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "user=me password=openupitsme host=my.host.not.yours dbname=mydb sslmode=require")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Cannot connect to db: ", err)
  }
  http.HandleFunc("/page", myHandler)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  log.Println("Handling Request....", r)
  query := `SELECT pk FROM mytable LIMIT 1`
  rows, err := Db.Query(query)
  if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
  }
  defer rows.Close()
  for rows.Next() {
    var pk int64
    if err := rows.Scan(&pk); err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println(pk)
  }
  log.Println("Request Served...")
}
```

EDIT #1:
My postgres log shows:

```
2015-07-08 18:10:01 EDT [7710-1] user@here LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2015-07-08 18:20:01 EDT [7756-1] user@here LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: There should be an error message. "the query hangs" is not descriptive enough.

Comment: is the DB located on the same machine as the app, or is it separate? Are firewalls / NAT involved (where state could be timing out due to inactivity.  When the app hangs does a netstat still show the connection as active?

Comment: Where are you running the db? Is it on heroku? Heroku "sleeps" if not used hence the next live query will take time. Also, please note that you dont need to open and close connections for every query, but you should have a close statement in the end of your program.

Comment: @AnshuPrateek Note that a `defer db.Close()` in `main()` won't get executed if your application is sent a `SIGINT` (via the keyboard or a process manager) - you'd have to explicitly catch that case. It won't functionally make a difference for most applications.

Comment: @Doon The database is hosted on an external server running a vanilla Ubuntu install w/ Postgresql 9.4

Comment: @zerkms I am printing errors on query execution as well as when I scan the rows. There is no error reported...unless I am not handling my error correctly in my code.....The query usually runs in less than 1 second but if I leave the app running and come back & execute again the query takes a loooooong time. I can then restart the app & run the query again and it runs, again, in less than a second.

Comment: Look at setting `db.SetMaxIdleConns(x)` (5 - 10 idles is a good starting point). Without it, there can be some setup time for the pool to re-auth and provide you with a usable connection.

Comment: @elithrar that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does it have no effect? What do your Postgres server logs (under `/var/log/postgres`) indicate at the time your Go application appears to "hang" on reconnect?

Comment: @elithrar please see my edit for the log

Comment: It appears the client is timing out. I assume your client is running on your local machine? (since you say the database is on an external server). Is it possible your local machine is sleeping and causing a timeout?

Comment: My client is running on my local machine. The above code is also running on my local machine & postgresql is on a remote machine. I hit "127.0.0.1:8080/page" in chrome. I wouldn't think chrome sleeps but even if it did why doesn't it sleep when I restart the above code?

Comment: Chrome won't sleep, but your computer (running your Go server) might. If your Postgres connection times out *every 16 minutes* (consistently) then it would point to a sleep/suspend issue. 15 minutes is a common "my laptop sleeps now" setting. (note that I'm taking a stab here - there's not enough information to genuinely solve this directly)

Comment: I would agree with those above, since you are dealing with two separate system. The server can be closing the connection regardless of what your client wants or is doing. This isn't my language, but conceptually would it be so harmful to just open and then close the connection as you need it?

Comment: @DavidCarrigan In Go the DB connection is meant to be long-lived...if that's the case then we shouldn't need to constantly close & re-open connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experienced similar issues. In our case, the problem was caused by a connection tracking firewall located between the client machine and the database.

Such firewalls keep track of TCP level connections, and in order to limit resource usage, then will time out connections which to them appear inactive for an extended period. The symptoms we observed in this case were very similar to yours: at the client end, the connection appears to be hanging, while at the server end you can see `connection reset by peer`.

One way to prevent this is to ensure that [TCP Keepalives](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) are enabled, and that the keepalive interval is less than the timeout of the firewalls, routers, etc which are causing your connection issue. This is controlled by the libpq connection parameters `keepalives`, `keepalives_idle`, `keepalives_interval` and `keepalives_count` which you can set in the connection string. See the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) for a description of these parameters.

- `keepalive` determines if the keepalive function is enabled or not. It defaults to `1` (enabled) so you probably do not need to specify this.
- `keepalives_idle` determines the amount of idle time before it will send a keepalive. If you do not specify this, it will default to the default for the operating system.

  In a Linux system you can see the default by examining `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time` - in my server it is set to 7200 seconds, which would be too long in your case, since your observation is that the connection is dropped after ~1 hour.

  You could try setting it to, say, 2500 seconds.

The Linux Documentation Project provides a useful [TCP Keepalive HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/) document that describes how they work in some detail.

Note that not all operating systems support TCP keepalives. If you are unable to enable keepalives here are some other options you might like to consider:

1. If it is in your control, reconfigure the firewall/router which is dropping the connection so that it will not do so for Postgresql client connections
2. At an application level, you might be able to send some traffic that will keep the DB handles active - for example sending a statement such as `SELECT 1;` every hour or so. If your programming environment provides connection caching (from the comments I gather it does) then this might be tricky.